# How To convert this list in unix timestamps to date python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

**This is the list of in unix timestamp**

[1626325266384,
1626328880748,
1626332547188,
1626336091854,
1626339628069,
1626343243866,
1626415257315,
1626418895970,
1626422492406,
1626426036647,
1626429722183,
1626433273664,
1626436849458,
1626440458241,
1626444063135,]

**Tried almost everything but nothing helped.**

Comment: There are plenty of articles about converting Unix timestamps to datetime objects in Python. What part are you having trouble with? You could try this: `datetimes = [datetime.fromtimestamp(t) for t in timestamps]`, where `timestamps` is your list of timestamps.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and how it didn't work? Did you try dividing the values by 1000?

Comment: for i in unixLst:    ext = (timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

Comment: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Im getting this error when i ran datetimes = [datetime.fromtimestamp(t) for t in timestamps], where timestamps @Matthias Fripp

Comment: It looks like you have JavaScript timestamps (milliseconds), not Unix timestamps (seconds). Try dividing by 1000, then using datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp().

Answer (score 2):

Your timestamp contains milliseconds.
This is a feasible solution:

```
import datetime
timestamp_with_ms = 1626325266384
dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_with_ms / 1000)
formatted_time = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
print(formatted_time)
# 2021-07-15 07:01:06.384
```

Your specific case requires also a `for loop`:

```
my_list = [1626325266384, 1626328880748, 1626332547188, 1626336091854, 1626339628069, 1626343243866, 1626415257315, 1626418895970, 1626422492406, 1626426036647, 1626429722183, 1626433273664, 1626436849458, 1626440458241, 1626444063135]

import datetime
new_list=[]
for i  in my_list:
    timestamp_with_ms = i
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_with_ms / 1000)
    formatted_time = dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
    new_list.append(formatted_time)
```

results:

```
 ['2021-07-15 07:01:06.384',
 '2021-07-15 08:01:20.748',
 '2021-07-15 09:02:27.188',
 '2021-07-15 10:01:31.854',
 '2021-07-15 11:00:28.069',
 '2021-07-15 12:00:43.866',
 '2021-07-16 08:00:57.315',
 '2021-07-16 09:01:35.970',
 '2021-07-16 10:01:32.406',
 '2021-07-16 11:00:36.647',
 '2021-07-16 12:02:02.183',
 '2021-07-16 13:01:13.664',
 '2021-07-16 14:00:49.458',
 '2021-07-16 15:00:58.241',
 '2021-07-16 16:01:03.135']
```

Comment: What should i do if my input is a list of unix timestamps!

Comment: You already know how to write a loop.

Comment: how do i assign a variable to the output of my loop

Comment: Create an empty list before loop, then append results to it. See my edited answer.